# Get error output from vbscript

Tags: c#, vbscript, error-handling

How can I correctly get error output from runnung vbscript in C#?

Here is my code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cscript");
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

p.OutputDataReceived += (proc, outLine) => MessageBox.Show(outLine.Data, 
                                                            "Data:", 
                                                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                                                            MessageBoxIcon.Information);
p.ErrorDataReceived += (proc, outLine) => MessageBox.Show(outLine.Data, 
                                                            "error!", 
                                                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                                                            MessageBoxIcon.Error);

p.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\\test.vbs";

p.Start();

p.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

This way I am able to get data from cscript, but if there is an error in the script - process is simply closed, without a message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOps. My fault - I forgot to add

```
p.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

And that is the answer